# Centre Blog Index (Posts Page) on Home.php

Tags: posts, css, theme-twenty-seventeen

My site is: https://dev.theartofsongs.com/blog/

I have my blog index (posts page) run through the home.php file. I would like to centre the posts within the page. What CSS do I need to add to my child themes CSS file to achieve that on just that page?

Thanks

Ali

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Since this is a purely CSS question you may get more help over on Stack Overflow, or looking for tutorials on how to inspect an element and determine how to target the right element.

Comment: Ok thanks Elaine, I'll try on Stack Overflow. I have tried inspecting the element and when I've altered what I think I need to alter it doesn't seem to work.